# Why Eclipse has ignored the .project file?

Tags: java, eclipse

I imported a java project in eclipse:

- In eclipse, the project name is shown as the directory name
- In '.project' file, the project name was overridden to a different name than the directory name

As far as I know, the name taken by eclipse should be the one stated in the '.project' file, not the project directory name.
So I want to know why eclipse has ignored the .project file?

**PS:** '.project' file was generated by gradle eclipse task

Comment: It's simple do. First switch the work space at particular folder, where you put the project. Then import the project. Solved !!

Answer (score 2):

The name in the .project files sets the name value in the `IProjectDescription` for the project (see `IProject.getDescription()`).

The name in the project description is used as the default for the project name while creating the project but the final name is always the last part of the project path.

The code for this is in `org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project`

Comment: Hi greg, thanks for your answer.
I have read the code and I could confirm what you said.
However, I don't understand how build tools like gradle manage to override the name without changing project folder name, I though they do it by manipulating the .project file, so if it is not the case then how they do it ?

Comment: Note that there can be two paths for a project - the actual location path and the  path in the workspace (always just '/xxxx') these can be different. In the 'Resource' page of the project properties these are shown as 'Location' and 'Path'

Comment: And for the workspace path how it is computed ?
AFAIK, when I run "gradle eclipse" only two files are generated: .project and .classpath, so the rest of workspace metadata files are forcefully generated from those files.
 
My problem is that I have defined a project name in the settings.gradle, but eclipse ignores always this name and instead of that it displays the last part of the location path as the project name.
I have checked the .project file: the name is the one provided by the gradle setting.
so I don't really understand why eclipse still showing me the wrong name

Comment: It is determined by the name given to `IWorkspaceRoot.getProject` and the `IProjectDescription` passed to `IProject.create`. I don't use gradle and have no idea what it does when creating a project.